# What do I need to know before upgrading the CPU of a laptop?

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have an AMD laptop, which has AMD APU (e1-2500). I don't really like the speed of it and would love to upgrade to faster APU. There are some AMD APUs available in ebay. So the question is:

What do I need to check to be sure that a new APU will work without problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the main things you have to check is the socket type, and that the motherboard actually supports that type of processor (sometimes a bios Flash update is required, other times a whole new motherboard is the only option)

However, in your situation there is a problem:
The E1-2500 is a BGA769 (FT3) APU, based on Kabini core. BGA = Ball Grid Array. This type of 'socket' is used to permanently attach a processor to its motherboard during production, making future upgrades impossible.

In other words, to upgrade your laptop, you will need to get a whole new motherboard/APU combo that was designed for your particular laptop series.

Comment: 'designed for you particular laptop series' is how most go, they make hard drives and RAM easily upgradeable because they are universal sizes and connections, there are regular CPU socket changes, the case was designed to house specific parts

Answer (score 2):

1. **Most important** : Every processor comes sized to fit a particular `CPU socket` as you've chosen your motherboard already then you'll know what this is; if not, then now might be a good time to think about it, as your processor will need to be compatible.
2. Will your `PSU` handle an upgrade?
3. How much RAM do you have? According to your memory size, maybe any further upgrade won't be useful!
4. Are your other components going to bottleneck any upgrade?

Comment: Weird but my laptop came with plenty of ram(6GB) and with slow CPU, so I guess it will be ok

Comment: @khajvah Yes, It seems enough at least in the next few years :)