# Is it possible to use an AMD A4 APU on AMD E1 mainboard?

Tags: motherboard

I would like to change my AMD E1 APU with an AMD A4 APU. Is the socket BGA and BGA-413 the same? Is that possible and would it work?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/733630/what-do-i-need-to-know-before-upgrading-the-cpu-of-a-laptop/733643#733643 is roughly the same. I also suspect the E stands for *embedded*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, BGA stands for ball grid array. It's a way of soldering the CPU directly to the motherboard. You will not be able to replace the cpu in your system at all without replacing the motherboard as well.